# Erro na fabrica ao usar do @Embeddable no JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Preciso criar uma chave composta no meu sistema, apos pesquisar um pouco descobrir que deveria implementar o @Embeddable, ate tudo bem, adicionei a classe no meu sistema implementando as chaves, mas quando tento executar a fabrica indica um erro relacionado a problema do tipo de classe esperada.

Classe Entity

```
@Entity
public class Apartamento implements Serializable {


@EmbeddedId
private Chave chave;

private Long andar;

private String descricao;

private BigDecimal valor;

private Long quantidade;

//Contrutores, getts e settes //
```

Classe Embeddable

```
@Embeddable
public class Chave implements Serializable{

private Long id;
private String ala;

    public Chave() {}

public Chave(Long id, String ala) {
    this.id = id;
    this.ala = ala;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getAla() {
    return ala;
}

public void setAla(String ala) {
    this.ala = ala;
}



}
```

Metodo de inserção

```
 em.getTransaction().begin();
    Chave chave = new Chave(numero, ala);

    Apartamento ap = new Apartamento(chave, andar, descricao, valor, quantidade);
    em.persist(ap);

    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Classe da Fabrica do JPA

```
 public EntityManager getEM(){
    emf =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hotel");
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}
```

XML da minha persistencia

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<!--  unidade de persistencia com o nome financas  -->
 <persistence-unit name="hotel">
 <!--  Implementação do JPA, no nosso caso Hibernate  -->
 <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
 <!--  Aqui são listadas todas as entidades  -->
<class>entity.Apartamento</class>
<class>entity.Contato</class>
<class>entity.Hospede</class>
<class>entity.Admin</class>
<properties>
  <!--  Propriedades JDBC  -->
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
  <!--  Configurações específicas do Hibernate  -->
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
</properties>
```

Erro descrito pelo sistema

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class entity.Apartamento. Expected: class entity.Chave, got class java.lang.Long
```

No caso o erro indica exatamente na `em.getTransaction().begin();` ou seja quando a conexão e iniciada para que a inserção no banco aconteça.

Answer (score 1):

Na sua classe Chave não existe uma chave composta, ou seja, você não tem 2 ou mais id's, outra coisa você tem que identificar o que é chave no seu código, exemplo:

```
@Id
private Long id;
```

No caso de usar somente uma chave conforme seu código, você não precisa usar @*Embeddable*, somente instanciar a classe. Como você esta usando *Hibernate*, acredito que você esteja fazendo confusão com @*ManyToOne*, nesse caso você instancia a classe assim:

```
@Entity
public class Apartamento implements Serializable {
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_chave")
private Chave chave;
```

Aconselho você dá uma olhada em relacionamento entre entidades no *hibernate*.

Comment: no caso estou usando @Embeddable por que a chave composta não vem de uma outra tabela, tanto que no banco de dados ela e inexistente.

Comment: No caso você esta considerando 'id' e 'ala' da classe Chave como pk?

Comment: não, elas são chaves primarias da tabela apartamento, a tabela Chave não existe

Comment: Entendi. Dá uma olhada nesse site, acredito que ele vai lhe ajudar nesse problema: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-composite-primary-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/